# cocoa:How to make the icon has been relying on the right?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

this window status bar.How to make the icon has been relying on the right ? Resize the window , it automatically to the right .

[image]

```
-(void)composeInterface{
    NSView *themeFrame=[[self.window contentView] superview];
    NSRect themeFrameRect = [themeFrame frame];
    NSRect accessoryViewFrame =[self.statusBarBtn frame];
    NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(30,
                                 themeFrameRect.size.height - accessoryViewFrame.size.height,
                                 accessoryViewFrame.size.width,
                                 accessoryViewFrame.size.height);

    [self.statusBarBtn setFrame:newFrame];
//    [self.statusBarBtn setFrameOrigin:NSMakePoint(0, 0)];
//    [self.statusBarBtn setAutoresizingMask:323];

    [themeFrame addSubview:self.statusBarBtn];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want that Your icon will be aligned to the right You need to change it's *Autosizing* to align right. You need to do it like this in ***Size Inspector*** :

[image: Size Inspector]

Or just use `-setAutoresizingMask` like this:

```
[self.statusBarBtn setAutoresizingMask:333]; //NOT 323
```

Furthermore Your `newFrame`'s x possition is set to 30, so the icon will be in the left side.

**Change this:**

```
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(30,
                             themeFrameRect.size.height - accessoryViewFrame.size.height,
                             accessoryViewFrame.size.width,
                             accessoryViewFrame.size.height);
```

**To this:**

```
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(themeFrameRect.size.width - accessoryViewFrame.size.width,
                             themeFrameRect.size.height - accessoryViewFrame.size.height,
                             accessoryViewFrame.size.width,
                             accessoryViewFrame.size.height);
```

Comment: @孤魂楚 Because if You use 323 - Your button's width will be changed when resizing window and align will be just to right, not top and right. No problem, glad that helped.